# I am Getting warning message on Browser while using jsf primefaces

Tags: primefaces

I am Using primefaces and Jsf with glassfish when i try to execute this code

```
 <p:menubar autoSubmenuDisplay="true" effect="slide">
                    <p:submenu label="File" icon="ui-icon ui-icon-gear">
                        <p:menuitem value="Logout" url="#" />
                    </p:submenu>
                    <p:submenu label="Goto" icon="ui-icon ui-icon-gear">
                        <p:menuitem value="Enhancement Catalog" action="#{adminControlBean.eAMChat}" id="submit1"  ajax="false" />
                        <p:menuitem value="Proceed to Chat" action="#{adminControlBean.enhancementCatalog}" id="submit2" />
                        <p:menuitem value="Customer Maintanence" action="#{adminControlBean.customerMaintanance}" id="submit3" />
                        <p:menuitem value="Moderator Maintanence" action="#{adminControlBean.moderatorMaintanance}"  id="submit4" />
                        <p:menuitem value="Chat Protocols" action="#{adminControlBean.chatProtocalMaintanance}" id="submit5" ajax="false" />
                    </p:submenu>
                    <p:submenu label="Edit" icon="ui-icon ui-icon-gear">
                        <p:menuitem value="Change Password" action="#{password.submitAction}" id="submit"  />
                    </p:submenu>
                </p:menubar>
```

I am getting warning message as

> The form component needs to have a UIForm in its ancestry. Suggestion: enclose the necessary components within `<h:form>`

Please let me know where i made a mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a bug in the JSF 2.1 implementation.

Se [this primefaces issue](http://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/detail?id=1586) for details

Answer (score 5):

well based on the link mentioned above [a user suggested](http://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/detail?id=1586) to change this:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
    <param-value>Development</param-value>
</context-param>
```

to:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
    <param-value>Production</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Hope this helps...it just gets rid of the message here, although the underlying problem is within PF implementation as the discussion there seems to imply.

Answer (score -1):

You need to enclose the form components, like inputtext, checkbox, inputhidden, etc. into a form tag.
The "Production" param value only hidden the warning, is not a fix.

Comment: Although your statement is not false, it was not the reason for this error to happen in thisase. The accepted answer was the cause.